# Is there a way to make Rails ActiveRecord attributes private?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, private

By default, ActiveRecord takes all fields from the corresponding database table and creates public attributes for all of them.

I think that it's reasonable *not* to make all attributes in a model public. Even more, exposing attributes that are meant for internal use clutters the model's interface and violates the encapsulation principle.

So, is there a way to make some of the attributes literally `private`?

Or, maybe I should move on to some other ORM?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Jordini was most of the way there

Most of active_record happens in method_missing. If you define the method up front, it won't hit method_missing for that method, and use yours instead (effectively overwriting, but not really)

```
class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base

  private

  def my_private_attribute
    self[:my_private_attribute]
  end

  def my_private_attribute=(val)
    write_attribute :my_private_attribute, val
  end

end
```

Comment: Any reason why I wouldn't/couldn't use the following to accomplish this?
    private
        attr_accessor my_private_attribute

Comment: @TC: because those won't actually track the attributes properly. the write_attribute / read_attribute methods are the way you interface with active_record

Comment: actually, write_attribute won't persist the value to DB. One would have to call self.save afterwards to actually update the record in the DB.

Comment: From outside model I can do `your_model_instance[:my_private_attribute] = "Foo"` and change the attribute value. Very ugly!

Comment: @Overflow012 you can also do `your_model_instance.send(:my_private_attribute=, "foo")`. Ruby takes the (sane) approach that the goal of privacy is an indicator of intent to other programmers, not as a lock that can never be broken.

Comment: `def my_private_attribute; super end` will do - no need to redefine it, then of course make it private as above or in my preferred way `private :my_private_attribute`

Answer (score 6):

Stumbled upon this recently. If you want private writing and reading and public reading something like this

```
class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_reader :attribute

  private

  attr_accessor :attribute


end
```

seems to work fine for me. You can fiddle with attr_reader, attr_writer and attr_accessor to decide what should be exposed and what should be private.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this won't work with regular AR attributes, since they are not stored in instance variables (which attr_* methods work with).

Comment: I looked for this answer everywhere! Looks like it worked and was EXACTLY what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: From outside model I can do `your_model_instance[:my_private_attribute] = "Foo"` and change the attribute value. Very ugly!

Answer (score 5):

well, you could always override the methods...

```
class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base

  private

  def my_private_attribute
    self[:my_private_attribute]
  end

  def my_private_attribute=(val)
    self[:my_private_attribute] = val
  end

end
```

Comment: It seems that this gives an error when using update from the model class.

Answer (score 2):

For me methods from both Otto and jordinl are working fine and make rspec for object of Class to pass:

```
object.should_not respond_to :attribute
```

But when I use jordinl method, I have a deprecation message to not write to database directly, but use attr_writer instead.

UPDATE:

But the truly "right" metod to do it turns out to be simple. Thanks to Mladen Jablanović and Christopher Creutzig [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171743/make-instance-methods-private-in-runtime). To make predefined method private or protected... simply redefine it:

```
Class Class_name

  private :method_name
  protected :method_name_1
end
```

What's important, you needn't rewrite previously defined method's logic.

Answer (score 1):

You can make an existing method private:

```
YourClass.send(:private, :your_method)
```

Comment: this actually doesn't work with ActiveRecord unfortunately as the accessor methods are not actually defined, they're created with method_missing and a bit of meta programming.

Answer (score 0):

Making the setting private does generate ActiveRecord error.

I put access control code in the overwritten method of the public setter by checking the caller:

```
def my_private_attribute=(val)
  if (caller.first.include?('active_record/base.rb') || caller.first.include?('app/models/myclass.rb'))
    self[:my_private_attribute] = val
  else
     raise Exception.new("Cannot set read-only attribute.")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is 100% reliable way to do this. It's also worth checking the most popular ways to access attributes:

http://www.davidverhasselt.com/set-attributes-in-activerecord/