# ActiveRecord: Attributes protected by default. How can they be public?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attributes, rails-activerecord

I have just started coding with rails. I am using: 
Rails 3.2.8
ruby 1.9.3p194

I created a migration and a corresponding model, all inside the files they should be ( I present them all together for conciseness):

```
class CreateMovies < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table 'movies' do |t|
    t.string 'title'
    t.timestamps
  end
end

def down
  drop_table 'movies'
end
end


class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

So, I would like to enter the 'rails console' and play around with the data base as a learning process.

This is what I enter and the error message I got:

```
1.9.3p194 :021 > k = Movie.new(:title => 'coco')
 ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: title
```

I have to say that the above statement works fine if I append :without_protection => true.

I looked up about mass-assignment and I understood that this is something we should be very careful about. BUT, it appears that rails activated mass-assignment protection by default. In my case I would like to create entries using hashes and this is extremely useful for debugging and learning!

Is there a way to de-activate this kind of protection? I would like to have public attributes by default! How can I achieve that ?

It is weird that, in my web research, I concluded that this feature is not there by default i.e. ActiveModel does not create protected attributes by default. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764899/is-there-a-way-to-make-rails-activerecord-attributes-private)
But in my case all attributes are private !

In my code, in the future, should I try to assign all attributes individually? This will be tedious. Is there a better way to have both security and avoid this tedious process ?

Thank you in advance from the depths of my heart!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No! Please don't de-activate this protection.  This is extremely helpful in stopping people from being able to set attributes they shouldn't. Turning it off is an *extremely bad idea* and I would *very, very strongly* advise against it.

You should be doing this in your model instead:

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title
end
```

This would make *just* the `title` attribute for your `Movie` object assignable, with nothing else able to be assigned without the `without_protection` flag or the `config.active_record.whitelist_attributes` setting set to `false`.

If you don't care to heed this warning then Murifox's answer is the one you want.

---

Imagine a situation where you have a form where a user is able to update their password. Innocent enough. Now imagine that you've turned off attribute protection and that your `users` table has an `admin` field on it.

It's actually incredibly easy for someone to save the HTML of the page to their computer, add in a field for `admin` and then set that to "on" or whatever, and then *blammo*, they're an admin for your site.

The new admin for your site quickly and effectively runs a *coup d'état* on your application, making what they claim to be "dissident data" disappear. Over future years, this brutal dictator somehow amasses enough nuclear material to form a nuclear weapon. He doesn't get along well with one of the lesser-known countries, let's say Suriname, and launches an attack with his army. How the army came to be is up to your imagination.

The hundreds of thousands of Surinamese (I had to look that up) are either killed or displaced into neighbouring countries, mainly French Guinea and Guyana. Some attempt to make it to Brazil, one of, if not *the* greatest country in South America, only to be killed by the sheer distance of the hike or creatures in the jungle.

The Surinamese Army, what remains of it, holds out against the dictator and his army. The stalemate is broken by the use of the nuclear weapon and the dictator adds Suriname and the lives of its populace to the list of things that he has ruined. The list is quite short: the only other thing he has ruined is your application.

**Do you want that on your conscious?!** *Why won't somebody think of the <s>Surinamese</s> attributes?!*

Please, I beg, use `attr_accessible`. Learn to love it, or else the consequences could be quite dire.

Comment: what a pressure you put on @MurifoX... +1 for illustration of the power of words :)

Comment: I know it is a vulnerability, but is there a way to set multiple attributes in a compact way ?

this is a toy example, but my actual db has lots of columns and it is really tedious to add entries. It is also tedious to add attr_accessible for every single project, class etc.

I am using a very new textbook (speaks ruby 1.9) from Coursera Saas and their examples use hashes to create db entries. Dunno how their examples actually work. But why is this happening by default? is this a particular ruby update ?

Comment: @iceiceice: This was a recent Rails update (Rails 3.2.3 I think?). The course books may not be updated to reflect this. I would really, really recommend that you just add each attribute that can be mass-assigned through a form to the list of accessible attributes, with `attr_accessible`

Comment: Thanks Ryan! I will always keep this on mind. I just wanted to play around in my machine locally. Thanks again for the response and advice.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :title, :as => :user
   attr_accessible :title, :disabled, :as => :admin
end
```

Now when you create a new movie, go like this:

```
k = Movie.create({:title => "A new movie"}, {:as => :user})
k.update_attributes({:disabled => true}, {:as => :admin})
```

Braces are optional but useful for explanation purpose. Now that means you can protect attribute for different roles. You could have a user role that can modify the title but cannot disabled a movie.

Now you can play around with this code and see for yourself that title and disabled accessor are unprotected for admin, but only title is accessible for the user role.

This make sure you don't have unauthorized access to children attributes and other critical attributes that are persisted, like Ryan Bigg mentionned.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this line to your application

```
config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true
```

restart server/console

check the official docs here

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#highlighter_14621

But I would suggest to starting living with it from start, do not deactivate it.
Its like a magical  key to open only the doors you want others to allow.

As per the my personal experience things learns during our first steps are what we follow mostly and are hard to change.just JMHO :)

Just add the fields to the model ass `attr_accessible`

```
class ModelName < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :column_1,:column_2,:column_3
end
```

and they will be accessible for mass assignemnt.
never make columns `user_active` or `admin` which hold very sensitive information as `attr_accessible`

you can always assign that value individually

eg: Lets assume a model `User` with a column which states user `active` or not and
`admin` column is not mass assigned

```
user = User.new(:active=>true)
user.save   #wont update the active column should throw mass assign assignment error

user = User.new
user.admin = true
user.save  #should save successfully
```

It takes a bit more efforts but then you can have a sound sleep :)

Comment: thanks! I will be serious about it. I wanted it for debugging/learning purposes.