# Prevent fetching password attribute value for an instance of User object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security, rails-models

I have this in my `:show` action of `users_controller`.

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

But there are some columns in the users table that I wouldn't want accessed from the `@user` instance variable.

There is the `encrypted_password` column and the `salt` column. What can i do on the model or the controller to ensure that `@user` has no `password` or `salt` values.

I want when I do `@user.password` or `@user.salt`, it returns `nil` or something that can't compromise a user's security.

Comment: You store the un-encrypted password?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Limiting your Ruby code from fetching some data from the DB hardly enhances security - chances are a hacker will get to your DB *not* through your ruby code, but by hacking straight to you database...
2. If all that is saved in the database is an *encrypted* password and the salt (both of which you need to authenticate the user) - you should be fine, having both is not enough to know the user's password (at least not easily, assuming the encryption is strong enough)
3. If you want to be *extra* careful, you can save the salt in a **separate** repository than the encrypted password repository. This way a hacker will have to break into *both* repositories to even start brute forcing your users' passwords.

Comment: I was worried with the salt and the encrypted password, a hacker can decrypt the password.

Comment: @pette if you are using a poor encryption algorithm, or a good algorithm incorrectly, this is possible.  If you are using a secure algorithm in the way it is intended, the likelihood of an attacker being able to recover the plaintext password from the encrypted password, even with the salt, is low.

Comment: @mcfinnigan I am using BCrypt, I am not sure whether that is good enough.

Comment: @pette just `using` Bcrypt is a good start, but you need to be using sane key sizes, not reusing keys or salts, etc.  Good security is not as simple as 'do this and you will be ok.    Have a read through this: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4781/do-any-security-experts-recommend-bcrypt-for-password-storage

Answer (score 2):

Don't store the password in the database in unencrypted format. Ever.

[Hiding an attribute in an ActiveRecord model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13463025/hiding-an-attribute-in-an-activerecord-model) provides some basic information on how you could hide various attributes in the model class.

The best approach would be to serve a facade to your controller from some intermediate object, and the facace would basically only expose those fields that the controler needed to manipulate.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an after_find callback in the model...

```
class User << ActiveRecord::Base
  after_find :nil_secure_fields

  def nil_secure_fields
    password = nil
    salt = nil
  end
end
```

If the record is updated you'd want to ensure the password and salt attributes aren't included in the attributes to update.

Comment: this solution isn't good, because: 1) attributes still will be accessible through `.attributes` method. 2) if you will need to update model you will set nils to secure fields

Comment: `:attributes` will show nil if the after_find has set them to nil (at least this is what I see in my testing).  Your second point is valid which is why calling 'save' would be bad.

Answer (score 0):

For `User` model add

```
class << self
  def find_secure(id)
    user = self.find(id)
    user.secure_attributes!
    user
  end
end

def secure_attributes!
  @attributes_secure = true
end

def secure_attributes?
  !!@attributes_secure
end

def encrypted_password
  secure_attributes? ? nil : super
end

def salt
  secure_attributes? ? nil : super
end
```

Now you can use `find_secure` method instead of `find` which will restrict access to secure attributes.

PS This is not obviate the need to store passwords encrypted.

Comment: Again, this does not address the core antipattern of storing sensitive data like unhashed passwords in the database - this is not something you want to do, and monkeypatching ActiveRecord to try to get around it is not the correct approach.

Comment: Where am I wrote that you should store unhashed passwords? Op asks about attributes access restriction and here is the correct solution. And this isn't monkey-patching, this is polymorphism/metaprogramming.