# Private/protected accessors to attributes in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, encapsulation

Supose that I have the following class:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :bar
end
```

In rails console I can do this:

```
foo = Foo.new
foo.bar_id = 3
```

But this can violates the encapsulation principle. I think that is better idea do:

```
foo = Foo.new
foo.bar = Bar.find(3);
```

And `bar_id` should be private/protected.
This has nothing to do with the `mass assignment` and `strong parameters` but it is an security issue too.

Is there any way to set to private some attributes?

Answer (score 0):

[Is there a way to make Rails ActiveRecord attributes private?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764899/is-there-a-way-to-make-rails-activerecord-attributes-private)

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base

  private

  def my_private_attribute
    self[:my_private_attribute]
  end

  def my_private_attribute=(val)
    write_attribute :my_private_attribute, val
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think just making the write accessor private or protected will reliably prevent change via `update_attribute` or mass assignment.

While it's not actually "private" per se, but you could get the desired effect by setting the attribute read_only, e.g.

`attr_readonly :bar_id`

and if you do need to update the value "private-ly," access it as @bar_id.  Per the docs, "Attributes listed as readonly will be used to create a new record but update operations will ignore these fields."